# Can I start the iPhone simulator without "Build and Run"?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I want to delete an app in the simulator before I "build and run". How can I start the simulator so I can do the deletion? If I start it by "build and run" I get a long log output that takes a while because of a bug I'm trying to fix. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 399, accepted):

The simulator is just an application, and as such you can run it like any other application.

To open it in Spotlight, search for `Simulator`.

To run the simulator straight from terminal, prepend these locations with the `open` command.

**Xcode 7.x, 8.x, 9.x, 10.x, 11.x, 12.x, 13.x, and 14.x**

In Xcode 7.x - 14.x, the iPhone Simulator has moved again: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`.

**Xcode 6.x**

In Xcode 6.x, the iPhone Simulator has moved yet again, and now resides here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator.app`.

---

**Xcode 4.x, 5.x**

In Xcode 4.x (through 4.5 on Mountain Lion) and Xcode 5.0.x on Mavericks, it lives here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/`

In my version of Xcode (4.5.2), I find it quite convenient to use the `Open Developer Tool` menu from either the dock icon or the Xcode menu:

[image: open iOS Simulator]

---

**Xcode 3.x**

In Xcode 3.x, it lives here:

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app`

---

In some future version of Xcode, it will probably move again, it's a squirrelly little app.

Comment: @jimbojw - It's a application bundle, so yes it's a folder too. If you double-click it (or use the `open` terminal command), it will run. Incidentally, it's called "iOS Simulator.app" with newer iPhone SDKs.

Comment: The full path I found this at was `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app`

Comment: Also note that if you go the path in the above comment in Finder, you can just drag the simulator down into your dock like any other app.

Comment: Do you guys know if there's a way to change it to other iOS simulator? ie iPhone 4 and iPads (retina and non-retina)

Comment: I found it at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iOS Simulator.app" .  To change devices, from within the simulator app, click Hardware > Devices.

Comment: For Xcode 7 the app is now simply named Simulator.app. Guess this also makes more sense, since it also simulates lots of other iOS devices than the iPhone.

Comment: How to change simulator type in this case ? Each time it opens same one

Comment: confirmed the instructions for Xcode 7, 8, and 9 still works for Xcode 12.3.

Answer (score 68):

From Terminal you can use:

```
open -a iPhone\ Simulator
open -a iOS\ Simulator
open -a Simulator
```

This all depends on the application name of the simulator, this can change with each iteration of Xcode.

Comment: This is the easiest solution by far. If it doesn't work, try with `iOS\ Simulator` instead.

Answer (score 48):

**To pick a specific** simulator you can first open the Simulator application

[image]

Then right click on the icon, and select from the devices.

[image]

Comment: This should be picked the best answer

Answer (score 35):

Since XCode 4.3 the location has changed, the simulator can now be found at:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/

Answer (score 24):

To follow up on that the new command from @jimbojw to create a shortcut with the new Xcode (installing through preferences) is:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app /Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Which will create a shortcut in the applications folder for you.

Answer (score 20):

Use **Spotlight**.

But only the last simulator will be opened. If you used `iPad Air 2` last time, Spotlight will open it. If you wanna open `iPhone 6s` this time, that's a problem.

[image]

Comment: You can select different device by navigating to File -> Open Simulator menu.

Answer (score 8):

This is an older question, but if you simply want to run the simulator from the Xcode 4.5 UI, you can do:  Xcode > Open Developer Tool > iOS Simulator.

Comment: The Open Developer Tool menu is also accessible by right-clicking on Xcode in the Dock. https://www.facebook.com/mattdipasquale/posts/880720811276

Comment: @joeriks I know exactly how you feel!  I spent 10 years working at MSFT on Windows!

Answer (score 7):

First, add the iOS Simulator to Applications:

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app /Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

From there you can open it in Finder or drag it to the launch bar.

Source: http://www.bram.us/2010/05/05/xcode-iphone-simulator-location/

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is start the simulator from the `Xcode`, and then on the dock, `Ctrl` + `Click` on the icon and select `Keep in Dock`[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without opening Xcode:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app/
```

Comment: To that, I added an alias to ~/.bash_profile: `alias ios="open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app"` which lets me just run `ios` from the command line.

Comment: FYI, on my machine the application is just `Simulator.app` not `iOS Simulator.app`.

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 7.2

open  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator.app

sudo ./Simulator

And adding this path in your profile is the best way.