# ios - when archiving getting strange new errors that were not there before

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I am getting an error like this:

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fundraising-ejuvymrlffmggbafituyflpzvhsh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fundraising/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Fundraising.app.dSYM /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fundraising-ejuvymrlffmggbafituyflpzvhsh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fundraising/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Fundraising.app/Fundraising
    cd /Users/owner12/Desktop/Fundraising
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fundraising-ejuvymrlffmggbafituyflpzvhsh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fundraising/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Fundraising.app/Fundraising -o /Users/owner12/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fundraising-ejuvymrlffmggbafituyflpzvhsh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Fundraising/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Fundraising.app.dSYM
```

I am not very sure what is this .dSYM file, and why it started causing issues now. Or maybe something else is the issue?

As a note, I have recently started getting some strange behavior from my mac where it says it can't save files due to memory shortage, but there is plenty of memory left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try closing and restarting Xcode; delete the application from device and reinstall it again. If this doesn't work, then your project might be missing some file. Maybe some file didn't copy to your project, it will show in a red color in your target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, if that's the case, delete it and add it again

Comment: thanks! How do I delete the project from the emulator device?

Comment: I did try restarting xCode and it does change the error so there may be multiple things going on here.

Comment: same as the device, to delete the app, just long-press the icon on the home screen, and it will start to wiggle and a cross will appear, press it to delete

Comment: I tried getting the emulator working to delete apps from it, but I could not run the app due to those errors. Is there a way to just open the emulator?

Comment: yes there is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048524/can-i-start-the-iphone-simulator-without-build-and-run